# How can i improve my code ? Rails polymorphic association best practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

An activity can have multiple types of participants ( parents, children, or a complete family ).

My tables are: Activity, Parents, Children, families and Activity_items to make the join. 
Routes : activity_items are nested under activities.

Activity_items have an activity_id field to link a participant to an activity. They also have activity_itemable_id and type to link a parent a child or a family ( here is the polymorphism )

The goal is to make list of participants of an activity at a specific day. 
In the view#show of an activity you can see the details an you can add a participant ( create an item ).

Where i'm pretty sure that my code isn't proper :

Create action in the activity_items controller :

```
  def create
   @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
   @activity_item = @activity.activity_items.new(activity_itemable_id: params[:itemable_id], activity_itemable_type: params[:itemable_type])
```

And the link_to in the view to create this item ( add a participant )

```
<% @parents.each do |p| %>
   <li>
     <%= link_to "#{p.firstname} #{p.lastname}", activity_activity_items_path(@activity, itemable_id: p.id, itemable_type: p.class.name), method: :post %>
   </li>
<% end %>
```

That's the only way i found by myself to create a good activity_items with the needed params.

The basic (params[:activity_item]) was not working so i decided to get the params like above.

I was watching the railscasts about polymorphic association and i was wondering how i can improve my old code.

Any documentation about this question is welcome, i didn't find something for my needs.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to refactor the controller and the view a little bit but i'm not sure if it's a "good" code:

the controller :

```
def create
  @activity = Activity.find(params[:activity_id])
  @activity_item = @activity.activity_items.new(params[:activity_item])
```

And the view:

```
<% @parents.each do |p| %>
       <li>
        <%= link_to "#{p.prenom} #{p.nom}",
            activity_activity_items_path(
              @activity,
              activity_item:{
                              activity_itemable_id: p.id,
                              activity_itemable_type: p.class.name
                              } ),
            method: :post %>
      </li>
<% end %>
```

The params are now clearer and the controller is more "generic".